# Defining the location a section is rendered in a view

Tags: .net, razor, sections

I'm interested in rendering sections at difference locations based on the page level, not the template level, is this possible?  For instance:

**Template:**

```
<body>
@if (IsSectionDefined("oneColumn")) {
  @RenderSection("oneColumn", false)    
  <div class="row">             
     @RenderSection("oneColumn_1", true)
  </div>
}

@if (IsSectionDefined("twoColumn")) {
@RenderSection("twoColumn", false)  
  <div class="row">             
    @RenderSection("twoColumn_1", true)
    @RenderSection("twoColumn_2", true)
  </div>
}
</body>
```

**Page Level:**

```
@{
  Layout = "template.cshtml";
}

@section twoColumn{}    
@section oneColumn{}

@section twoColumn_1 { <div>THIS IS COLUMN 1 - ColSpan 1</div> }
@section twoColumn_2 { <div>THIS IS COLUMN 2 - ColSpan 2</div> }
@section oneColumn_1 { <div>THIS IS COLUMN 1</div> }
```

This always renders the oneColumn section above the twoColumn section. But I want the twoColumn above the oneColumn.  Hoping to do this without creating additional templates.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instruct where sections will be rendered in your "Page level", unless you introduce another level of sub-templating / partial view.

I'm assuming you don't want always to display two columns content above one column content.

If you want to be able to occasionally render two columns above the one column section, then add another section into your template (layout view) something like:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("oneColumnAfterTwo")) {
@RenderSection("oneColumnAfterTwo", false)  
  <div class="row">             
    @RenderSection("oneColumn_1", true)
  </div>
}
```

And modify your page/views to include `oneColumnAfterTwo` instead of `oneColumn` where needed.

Comment: Can you define sub-templating with an example?